# Angular como usar o disabled em um input matInput?

Tags: angular

Tenho meu HTML:

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate [formGroup]="form">
 <div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
     <input matInput type="text" class="form-control" 
         id="nome" formControlName="nome" />
     <app-campo-control-erro [control]="form.get('nome')" 
         label="Nome">
     </app-campo-control-erro>
   </div>
```

porém no `input` um `disabled=isMaps`, não funciona, como conseguir desabilitar o `input`?. (Versão Angular 8.0).

controller:

```
if(diretorio.nome == "Mapas") {
    this.isMaps = true;
}
```

Comment: Se está utilizando formulário reativo, não teria que validar isso no TS?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com essa nova versão do Angular 8.0
Realmente o disabled os campos inputs devem ficar no .ts

O HTML continuou assim:

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate [formGroup]="form">
 <div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
     <input matInput type="text" class="form-control" 
         id="nome" formControlName="nome" />
     <app-campo-control-erro [control]="form.get('nome')" 
         label="Nome">
     </app-campo-control-erro>
   </div>
```

já o meu controller.ts ficou assim:

```
if(diretorio.nome == "Mapas"){
  this.isMaps = true;
  this.form.get('nome').disable();
}
```

Questão respondida no SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569844/disable-input-on-angular-form